# I can't interpret if "blood feud" in this context is literal

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the [NY Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/05/09/us/politics/west-virginia-trump.html) titled: "Trump Figures Into a Political Blood Feud in West Virginia"

I read all through and found no signs of family ties among the candidates and thought the "blood feud" mentioned refers to the fact the characters involved has strong connections but due to English not being my native language I'm not sure if my interpretation is correct. Is that so?

Answer (score 2):

Originally, a 'blood feud' was a feud between families or clans in which cycles of retaliatory killings happened. Used figuratively, it can be used about a long-lasting feud between (e.g.) different sections or groups within a political party, as here.

> Blood feud
>
> A very long fight between two families or groups in which each group
> kills members of the other group in order to punish the group for
> earlier murders.

[Blood feud (Britannica Dictionary)](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/blood-feud)

Comment: that is very clarifying but if I'm not imterpreting it wrong from the article I think it refers to the same group in case the Republicans, two members of republicans party are facing off in election and that will test Trump influence over the voters so blood feud refers in my interpretation to these two candidate in same political spectre. I wanted to confirm if my interpretation is correct, if "blood feud" can also be used in that way

Comment: @ilmapav - the 'Republican-on-Republican blood feud developing in West Virginia' is between Representatives David McKinley and Alex Mooney and their respective supporters.

Comment: then apparently I've interpret it correctly. right?

Comment: @ilmapav - what do you think?

Comment: I think I've interpreted it correctly. But a learning mind is sometimes an insecure mind.